# reloading elisp code when debugging

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have some elisp code in smcho.el.

- The problem is whenver I change the functions in this file, I have to reload emacs.
  Is there any way to reload this elisp file only?
- (Added based on the answer) Is there any way to redo the previous loading easily? I guess M-x load-file and give the file name again over and over again can be improved.

Comment: Well if you've just edited the buffer M-x eval-buffer will work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M-x load-file will load an elisp file.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to the second question, the minibuffer stores history, so you don't need to type the command (or argument) in full each time. Repeatedly pressing <kbd>C-p</kbd> (or the up arrow) will cycle backwards through the relevant history. So you might type <kbd>M-x</kbd> then <kbd>C-p</kbd> to get `load-file` and then <kbd>C-p</kbd> again at the prompt to get the last filename you loaded.

If you are currently viewing the file you want to evaluate, then you can simply use `M-x eval-buffer`, or `M-x eval-region` to evaluate a sub-set of it.

You can also search the minibuffer history at the prompt with <kbd>C-r</kbd> and <kbd>C-s</kbd>